# EnterSynchronizationBarrier hangs in windows 8

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, windows-8

I tried to use new API for synchronization barriers from Windows 8, but the following simple code sometimes hangs in Windows 8:

```
#undef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0603
#include "windows.h"
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  SYNCHRONIZATION_BARRIER barrier;
  int count = 32;
  InitializeSynchronizationBarrier (&barrier, count, -1);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for (int thr_num = 0; thr_num < count; thr_num++)
  {
    threads.emplace_back ([thr_num]
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        EnterSynchronizationBarrier (&barrier, 0);
    });
  }

  for (auto &thr : threads)
    thr.join ();

  return 0;
}
```

Tested on Windows 8.1 64-bit on 32-core dual-Xeon E5 2630. It hangs roughly one time out of ten launches.
It seems that in windows 10 it works normally (on another machine). Is this a bug in windows 8 that got fixed, or this is not a correct usage of `EnterSynchronizationBarrier` (maybe you can't call it in a loop?). There're not much information about this function, have anybody even used it?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151123-00/?p=92161

Comment: Smells like a bug to me, FWIW.

Comment: If it works in Win10 then it does sound like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it matters years later, except perhaps to show that some problems are too obscure for Stack Overflow to deliver close attention in useful time, but your usage is correct, if extreme, and the stress you have put the called function to does look to have exposed its problems with memory barriers.

In your fragment, a synchronisation barrier is prepared for 32 threads and you create 32 threads which each proceed to 100000 phases of synchronised work. All 32 reach their call number N to EnterSynchronizationBarrier before all are released on their way to their call number N+1. It should work. It likely would if your phases had any substance.

The stress is that each phase between calls is just however few instructions are involved in looping back to repeat the call. While the last thread to end phase N is in its call, it signals the others to leave, and they have a good chance of leaving (and even of reentering the function to end their phase N+1) while the thread that ends phase N is still doing its internal bookkeeping.

In this bookkeeping are two counters. One, named Barrier according to Microsoft's symbol files, is decremented as threads enter the synchronisation barrier. The other, named LeftBarrier, is incremented as they leave it. The thread that ends a phase resets Barrier from LeftBarrier (which should be the count of all participating threads) and resets LeftBarrier to 1. Or so it goes as a simplification.

The complicated reality is that the Barrier count is overloaded: its high bit signifies the change of phase. If a thread that waits at the synchronisation barrier is spinning rather than blocking on an event, then what it checks for while spinning is whether the high bit in Barrier has changed. It therefore really matters exactly how the counters get reset in the ending thread's bookkeeping. The sequence is: read LeftBarrier; write LeftBarrier as 1; write Barrier as the old LeftBarrier with the high bit toggled.

What I think happens is that without a memory barrier, the Barrier count can be written before LeftBarrier, but because Barrier has a toggled high bit, a spinning thread comes out of its spin and increments LeftBarrier from another processor before the first resets it to 1. The increment gets lost, after which all bets are off because subsequent phases will find that LeftBarrier at the end of a phase is no longer the count of participating threads.

Windows 8 and 8.1 have no memory barrier here. Windows 10 does, though I believe it's in the wrong place and that Windows Vista and Windows 7 had it correctly between the two writes. The implementation was anyway reworked completely for Version 1607 so that it now uses the WaitOnAddress functionality, much as sketched by a later Raymond Chen blog than the one cited by one of your correspondents. At the time of the cited blog, Microsoft, though possibly not Raymond, surely knew of the function's two earlier code changes regarding memory barriers.